# What's the use of CollapsingToolbarLayout's toolbarId attribute?

Tags: android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

What is `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s `toolbarId` for? I can't find any description in Google and my AppBarLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout works properly without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by looking into the source code of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (`CTBL`).
`CTBL` in fact **doesn't need** a `toolbarId` set explicitly because it searches for a toolbar in its child views if no id is set. However, by setting a `toolbarId` we can optimize our code because then the `CTBL` doesn't have to search itself (which happens repeatedly).

[image]
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/appbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout.java